# double array output in C program

Tags: arrays, c, loops, scanf

I seem to stuck in a extremely simple question, but I cannot fix it and understand why.
Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 8

int main(void){
  int i, j;
  double nums[SIZE];
  double input;
  
  printf("Enter 8 doubles: ");
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    nums[i] = scanf("%lf", &input);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    printf("%lf ", nums[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Below is the result I got:

```
Enter 8 doubles: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
```

What is the main problem about my code? Thank you!

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of items scanned. You want to assign `input` to your array items.

Comment: Oh Yeah! I forgot that... I am too stupid to notice that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one and you should read  the data in variable with scanf because  return from scanf is the number of items of the argument list successfully read:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define SIZE 3

 int main(void){
   int i, j;
   double nums[SIZE];
   double input;

   printf("Enter 8 doubles: ");
   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
     scanf("%lf", &input);
     nums[i] = input;// or scanf("%lf", &num[i]); 
   }

   for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
     printf("%lf ", nums[i]);
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @Jabou Please let me know if this answer  works for you.

Answer (score 0):

scanf return number of elements scanned.

i think you meant:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    scanf("%lf", &nums[i]);
}
```